# Are there any security risks from user generated inline css

Tags: php, html, css, regex

```
<div style='user input here'></div>
```

Are there any security risks to storing user generated CSS code and outputting it. I'm aware that we can do this on literally any browser, I just want to make sure I'm mindful of anything that should be of concern when allowing users to put any code they want inside an attribute.

**Just adding to the question for more information**: What if a regex is used to only allow numbers(0-9), letters(a-z) and maybe a few other things like hashtag(#) for #000 or brackets(()) and commas(,), maybe full stops too(.) for rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5). percentages(%) too?

If I did regex with any of the above would that be a security risk? If so, then which ones would that be? And what about white listing only some CSS code, are there any CSS styles that are definitely not a security risk?

Comment: Nope, I think css can not be a security risk anyway )

Comment: Yes there are some security risks you should consider. Most in the form of XSS attacks. They can also load malicious background images etc.

Comment: You might wanna read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/how-dangerous-is-it-to-use-css-styles-from-an-untrusted-source)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not encode the user's string value, then they can exploit the html structure with quotation marks.

For example, this will do nothing:

```
<div style="<script>harmfulJavascript();</script>"></div>
```

But if you allow the user to <s>break</s> complete the html attribute with a quotation mark, then they can add anything to the DOM.

**User string:**

```
"><script>harmfulJavascript();</script></div>
```

**Result:**

```
<div style="">
    <script>harmfulJavascript();</script>">
</div>
```